# Putting the value of an argument into part of a regex in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

Is it possible to pass a variable to a function in vimscript, and then use that value in a search and replace regex?

For example:

```
function! AddTW5Links(tiddlerSetName) 

    %s/\(*\+\)\(\[\[\(.*\)\)\]\]/\1[[\3|\3 - $tiddlerSetName]]/g

endfunction
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the choice between using `:s` after `:exe`, or using `:s\=`.

Meaning (untested)

```
:exe 's/\(*\+\)\(\[\[\(.*\)\)\]\]/\1[[\3|\3 - '.a:tiddlerSetName.']]/g'
```

(beware of double-quote, you'll have to double all your backslashes with them)

Or

```
:s/\(*\+\)\(\[\[\(.*\)\)\]\]/=submatch(1).'[['.submatch(3).'|'.submatch(3).' - '.a:tiddlerSetName.']]'/g
```